# Does rosjava_core harm the normal ros install?

Tags: ros, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Based on the documentation and questions on rosjava, I am not certain whether installing rosjava replaces the normal ROS install or is just another library.  Could someone clear this up for me please?  I want to talk to an android device using ROS, but still need all of the normal ROS stacks.  How does this work?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69976/does-rosjava_core-harm-the-normal-ros-install?/) by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are going to create an overlay for rosjava. So there will be a different set of setup files that you will source to switch between workspaces. So, your packages should be fine given that you properly install rosjava. Try sticking to the document.

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1